# String replace in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I am trying to deobfuscate code. This code uses a lot of long variable names which are substituted with meaningful names at the time of running the code.

How do I preserve the state while searching and replacing?

For instance, with an obfuscated line like this:

```
${${"GLOBALS"}["ttxdbvdj"]}=_hash(${$urqboemtmd}.substr(${${"GLOBALS"}["wkcjeuhsnr"]},${${"GLOBALS"}["gjbhisruvsjg"]}-${$rrwbtbxgijs},${${"GLOBALS"}["ibmtmqedn"]}));
```

There are multiple mappings in *mappings.txt* which match above obfuscated line like:

```
$rrwbtbxgijs = hash_length;
$urqboemtmd = out;
```

At the first run, it will replace **$rrwbtbxgijs** with **hash_length** in the obfuscated line above. Now, when it comes across the second mapping during the next iteration of the outer while loop, it will replace **$urqboemtmd** with **out** in the obfuscated line.

### The problem is:

When it comes across first mapping, it does the substitution. However, when it comes across next mapping in the same line for a different matching string, the previous search/replace result is not there.

It should preserve the previous substitution. How do I do that?

I wrote a Perl script, which would pick one mapping from *mapping.txt* and search the entire obfuscated code for all the occurrences of this mapping and replace it with the meaningful text.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

($mapping, $input) = @ARGV;

open MAPPING, '<', $mapping
    or die "couldn't read from the file, $mapping with error: $!\n";

while (<MAPPING>) {

    chomp;
    $line = $_;
    ($key, $value) = split("=", $line);
    open INPUT, '<', $input;

    while (<INPUT>) {

        chomp;
        if (/$key/) {

            $_=~s/\Q$key/$value/g;
            print $_,"\n";
        }
    }
    close INPUT;
}
close MAPPING;
```

Answer (score 3):

To match the literal meta characters inside your string, you can use `quotemeta` or:

```
s/\Q$key\E/$replace/
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, I have updated my question. Could you please check it? I need to preserve the substitution stage. For instance, it makes one substitution in the line at a time. When, it finds another occurrence of a different mapping in the line, it should preserve the previous state. Which means, it should keep updating the same line as and when it finds a match.

Comment: @NeonFlash I understand every word you say, but have no idea what you mean. What does "preserve the substitution stage" mean? I assume you mean that you cannot check one key at the time. You might store the input file in an array instead of opening the file for each iteration. And save the print for last.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell Perl not to interpret the characters in $key:

```
s/\Q$key/$value/g
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I have updated the question. Could you please check it and suggest a good workaround for it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [B::Deobfuscate](http://p3rl.org/B%3a%3aDeobfuscate) and gradually enter variable names into its configuration file as you figure out what they do.

I'm a little confused about your request to save state.  What exactly are you doing/do you intend to do with the output?  Here's an (untested) example of doing all the substitutions in one pass, if that helps?

```
my %map;
while ( my $line = <MAPPING> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($key, $value) = split("=", $line);
    $map{$key} = $value;
}
close MAPPING;

my $search = qr/(@{[ join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %map ]})/;
while ( my $line = <INPUT> ) {
    $line =~ s/$search/$map{$1}/g;
    print OUTPUT $line;
}
```

Comment: Hi, that does seem useful however its very complicated. I would love to devote time to learn how to use it efficiently, however for the time being, is there a way to make my current script work? It is able to substitute the values properly, I just want it to preserve the state. Once a successful search/replace is done, it should be saved. The next, search/replace operation should work on the result of previous.

Comment: @Neon Flash: see added example/question in answer